# How to change the console position in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

How to change the console position in Xcode?
I'm using Mac OS and Xcode.

The console window is always on the bottom. Can I put the console window on the left or the right?

Or, if not, can I automatically get the console window to appear when I run Xcode?

Have a nice day!